# How to get response from URL in rails using httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, get, httparty

I want to get response data from the above URL and store the value in database.

URL:

```
`http://xxxx.com/delivery_reports?data=%7B%22requestId%22%3A%22546b384ce51f469a2e8b4567%22%2C%22numbers%22%3A%7B%22917566559950%22%3A%7B%22date%22%3A%222014-11-18+17%3A45%3A59%22%2C%22status%22%3A1%2C%22desc%22%3A%22DELIVERED%22%7D%7D%7D`
```

controller:

```
def create
    @delivery_report = DeliveryReport.new(delivery_report_params)

    @response = HTTParty.get('http://xxxx.com/delivery_reports')    
    hash = JSON.parse @response
    puts hash

    respond_to do |format|
      if @delivery_report.save
        format.html { redirect_to @delivery_report, notice: 'Delivery report was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @delivery_report }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

it shows JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at ' error.

Comment: Could that be saying there's a syntax error on line 757?

Comment: Silly thing to check, but could you use `delivery_reports.json` instead of just `delivery_reports`? Methinks you're trying to parse HTML as JSON (unless the app is checking request headers on the fly).

Comment: You should probably password protect that url and hide it from public view.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to parse with JSON an invalid JSON file. The response from server is an HTML.

Try to remove this line:

```
hash = JSON.parse @response
```

Should work!

If you need any information on the page requested, use nokogiri gem to parse the HTML instead of JSON.parse.

[EDIT]

You can try using `/delivery_reports.json` on URL to retrieve as a valid JSON from server.